# Facebook PHP SDK session identify user

Tags: php, facebook

PHP Session

```
Array
(
    [fb_499519323487644_code] => ...
    [fb_499519323487644_access_token] => ...
    [fb_499519323487644_user_id] => 123456
```

I have an app using facebook php sdk to log into my application.

My question is how can I identify user from facebook?

I have test few time and I notice the code and `access_token` always change.

Therefor the only one I can identify user is `user_id`, the problem is everyone knows `user_id`

will it safe if I user `session user_id` to identify user?

Comment: "the problem is everyone knows user_id" --- why is it a problem?

Comment: i mean is this secure enough? (although session is create by server)

Comment: "secure" is a vague term. What's wrong with using `user_id`?